# While loop printing incorrectly

Tags: java

I am reading in data from the user (exam score). Then I am checking the grade. After that I am displaying the grade. Then I am asking the user if they want to enter another grade, if they say yes then I am asking them to enter another exam score. But here I am using try/catch to validate the data type they are entering. If they enter anything other then integer then I am trying to loop again and ask if they want to enter another grade but display Enter integer error message also. However here the loop prints do you want to enter another grade twice and the exam score twice it prints the old score and it prints the do you want to enter another grade statement twice, why is this happening?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CatchingException {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score;
    String choice;
    boolean loop = true;


    try {
        System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
        score = scan.nextInt();


        do {
            if(score <40) {
                System.out.println("You FAILED");
            }else if(score >=40 && score <50){
                System.out.println("Your grade: PASS MARK");
            }else if(score >=50 && score <60) {
                System.out.println("Your grade: 2:2");
            }else if (score >=60 && score <70) {
                System.out.println("Your grade: 2:1");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Your grade: 1:1");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
            choice = scan.next();
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
                try{
                    score = scan.nextInt();
                }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.err.println("Enter Integer");
                    loop = false;
                }

            }
        }while(!loop);

    }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Incorrect Input ");
    }

    System.out.println("program terminated");
    scan.close();

}

  }
```

Comment: Please edit your text. It's almost impossible to read it.

Comment: @Pshemo I believe that OP deals with end-of-line left in the keyboard buffer by `nextInt`.

Comment: @PM77-1 `#nextInt()` doesn't "care" about whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying this with branching statements and labels!

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CatchingException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score;
        String choice;

        Main:
        while (true) { //this will continue until we call "break Main;"
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
                score = scan.nextInt();

                if (score < 40) {
                    System.out.println("You FAILED");
                } else if (score >= 40 && score < 50) {
                    System.out.println("Your grade: PASS MARK");
                } else if (score >= 50 && score < 60) {
                    System.out.println("Your grade: 2:2");
                } else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
                    System.out.println("Your grade: 2:1");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your grade: 1:1");
                }

                Prompt:
                while (true) { //this will continue until we call "break Prompt;"
                    System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
                    choice = scan.next();
                    try {
                        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                            continue Main; //OK. Start again at "Main:"
                        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                            break Main; //OK. We're done.
                        else {
                            System.err.println("Incorrect Input ");
                            continue Prompt; //whoops! try asking again.
                        }
                    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                        System.err.println("Incorrect Input ");
                        continue Prompt; //whoops! try asking again.
                    }
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect Input ");
                continue Main; //whoops! try another input.
            }
        }
        System.out.println("program terminated");
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you are setting the `loop` variable indicates that you want to keep iterating as long as `loop` is `true`. In that case, you should change `while(!loop);` to `while (loop);`

After that, you have to look at what happens if the user write "no" when asked if they want to enter a new grade. As it is (with the above change), you will keep iterating. To fix this, you could change

```
System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
choice = scan.next();
if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
    try{
        score = scan.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Enter Integer");
        loop = false;
    }
}
```

To something like

```
System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
choice = scan.next();
if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
    loop = false;
}
```

This will make any input (other than "*no*") cause the loop to keep iterating. (If you want only "*yes*" to work, then it should be quite easy to fix with some additional checks.)

Of course, doing this would require you to put

```
System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
score = scan.nextInt();
```

inside the `do-while` loop.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
    score = scan.nextInt();
```

---

If you want to keep asking for a percentage mark if the user does not enter a correct integer, you can do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid percentage mark: ");
    scan.next();
}
score = scan.nextInt();
```

This will keep asking until the user enters an actual integer.

Comment: the point of the program is basically, when the program asks Enter your percentage mark and the user enters anything else but a integer then the program should loop and once again ask do enter your percentage mark instead here the program goes into a infinite loop

Comment: Not sure what you mean. With my changes the code will not ask again on invalid input, that is right. But when I run the code and enter a non-integer, it prints "_Invalid Input_" and terminates. No infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is `why is this happening` I'll try to explain it to you. My example input is as follows:

```
Enter your percentage mark: 
70
Your grade: 1:1
Do you want to enter another grade: 
yes
Enter your percentage mark: 
a
```

`a` is no valid integer, therefore `Scanner#nextInt()` throws an `InputMismatchException` and the program "goes" into the `catch` block:

```
catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.println("Enter Integer");
    loop = false;
}
```

Here the program prints the error message and sets `loop` to `false`. Due to the `while` condition `while(!loop)` it is about to perform a new loop iteration. Mind that `Scanner#nextInt()` doesn't "read" (and remove) the invalid input from the input stream, therefore it is still there.

So we are here again:

```
do {
    if(score <40) {
        System.out.println("You FAILED");
    }
    //...
```

As you may notice, there is no `score = scan.nextInt();` statement here, therefore, the program reuses the old score input `70`. Due to that fact, it prints the same score message again (full output up to this point):

```
Enter your percentage mark: 
70
Your grade: 1:1
Do you want to enter another grade: 
yes
Enter your percentage mark: 
a
Enter Integer
Your grade: 1:1
```

After the score validation it will ask us again, if we like to enter another score:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
choice = scan.next();
```

And here is another problem: the `a` we've entered in the last iteration is still available and since `Scanner#next()` accepts this input, `choice` will now be `"a"`.
That is why this `if` statements returns false and its body will be skipped (`"a"` is not equal to `"yes"`):

```
if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
```

Our situation is now, that `a` is gone from the input stream and `loop` is still set to `false`. So, the program will take another loop iteration and we are at the beginning of the loop (again):

```
do {
    if(score <40) {
        System.out.println("You FAILED");
    }
    //...
```

And again, we're not reading a now score here. Instead we're reusing the old input of score `70`. That means, we get the exact same message:

```
Your grade: 1:1
```

The good thing is: `a` is gone from the input stream and the next question does in fact request a new input from the user:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
choice = scan.next();
```

So it is up to him to decide what he wants.

---

As you may see now, you need to read the invalid input in your `catch` block, or it will bother you later. And you should read the new `score` at the beginning of the `do/while` loop, or else you might reuse the old input instead.

I hope that answer helps you to understand your program a little bit more :). And you should take some time to learn how to use a debugger. It is very helpful in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there was no reason for you to do a do-while loop here. Unless this is like an homework exercise to demonstrate using do loops, you should really only use it if it either:
1) It makes the code easier to read
2) Makes the process easier

I had trouble reading your code myself. I just did this and it works fine. 
NOTE: I didn't add any try catch for this but if you must you know how to do it, as well as if the user doesn't enter yes or no. Just a basic example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score;
    String choice;
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your percentage mark: ");
        score = scan.nextInt();
        if(score <40) 
        {
            System.out.println("You FAILED");
        }
        else if(score >=40 && score <50)
        {
            System.out.println("Your grade: PASS MARK");
        }
        else if(score >=50 && score <60) 
        {
            System.out.println("Your grade: 2:2");
        }
        else if (score >=60 && score <70) 
        {
            System.out.println("Your grade: 2:1");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Your grade: 1:1");
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another grade: ");
        choice = scan.next();

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            System.out.println("Program terminated");
            scan.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```